# How can it show more than one checkbox

Tags: php, html

How can it show more than one checkbox ?The staff included Peter,Marry,Sam,Ken.

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $staff  = $row['staff'];
    }
    echo "<a class ='button' href='check.php?staff=".staff."'>click</a>";
  ?>

<html>
   <input type="checkbox" name="staff" value="<?php echo $_GET["staff"]; ?>">
</html>
```

The result like this photo :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the input fields inside your while loop :

```
<html>
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="staff" value="<?php echo $_GET["staff"]; ?>">
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate on `$results` and assign `$row['staff']` into input value.

```
<html>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="staff" value="<?php echo $row['staff'] ?>">
    <?php } ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can do 2 things
you can add you checkbox code inside while loop , or create $staff  array and fill it using loop and then loop throgh it

```
 Mthod 1 :



<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $staff  = $row['staff'];
       echo '<input type="checkbox" name="staff" value="'.$staff.' ; ?>">';
}
?>



Method 2 : 




<?php
    $staff_members = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
           $staff_members[]  = $row['staff'];
    }
    ?>

And in HTML

<?php 
    foreach($staff_members as $staff_member){
    $member = $staff_member;
       echo '<input type="checkbox" name="staff" value="'.$member.' ; ?>">';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Method 1 is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move showing the checkbox inside the loop.

```
<html>
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $staff  = $row['staff'];
        echo "<a class ='button' href='check.php?staff=$staff'>click</a>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='staff' value='$staff'>"
    }
?>
</html>
```

Useful [hint](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp): Using `echo "the value of x is $x"` will parse the variable $x in the double quoted string to its value. The result is easier to read than putting a whole PHP tag inside the element tag attribute.